# Check if the path is File or Folder using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to check if the path defined in the program is file or a folder using batch file. Everything is working fine but when I try to give a path that isn't file or folder or doesn't have permission to access it, it gives output saying "it is a File".

Here is the code.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set ATTR=D:\Download\Documents\New


dir /AD "%ATTR%" 2>&1 | findstr /C:"Not Found">NUL:&&(goto IsFile)||(goto IsDir)

:IsFile
  echo %ATTR% is a file
  goto done

:IsDir
  echo %ATTR% is a directory
  goto done

:done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following method:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "ATTR=D:\Download\Documents\New"
For %%Z In ("%ATTR%") Do If "%%~aZ" GEq "d" (Echo Directory
) Else If "%%~aZ" GEq "-" (Echo File) Else Echo Inaccessible
Pause
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048421/break-batch-if-else-statement-into-multiple-lines-hard-to-read-code

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a logical one: you check, if it's a folder, but you don't check, if it's a file, so you have either "folder" or "not a folder". You need another check for "file". But finding "Not Found" makes it language dependent, which generally should be avoided. Here is a language independent solution:

`for` does list all attibutes (there is a **D**irecotry attribute), which even `attrib` doesn't.

```
@echo off
break>Existing.File
md ExistingFolder

set "attr=Existing.File"
REM set "attr=ExistingFolder"
REM set "attr=does not exist"

for /f %%x in ("%attr%") do set attrib=%%~ax/
set "attrib=%attrib:~0,1%"
if "%attrib%"=="d" echo %attr% is a directory
if "%attrib%"=="-" echo %attr% is a file
if "%attrib%"=="/" echo %attr% does not exist
```

Note: this method even detects a folder, where you don't have access to (but does not detect such files)