# Break Batch If/ELSE Statement into multiple lines - Hard to Read Code

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error

I found this code here --> ::[Check if the path is File or Folder using batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954081/check-if-the-path-is-file-or-folder-using-batch)

But I find it hard to read and want to simplify it/break it apart. I'm not sure how to do this, I tried the below and a few variations to no avail. Can anybody help? Thanks!

**This code works:**

```
@Echo Off
Set "ATTR=D:\Download\Documents\New"
For %%Z In ("%ATTR%") Do If "%%~aZ" GEq "d" (Echo Directory
) Else If "%%~aZ" GEq "-" (Echo File) Else Echo Inaccessible
Pause
```

**This is what I would like it to look like, but can't figure out:**

```
@echo off

set "ATTR=%AppData%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART"

For %%Z In ("%ATTR%") Do If "%%~aZ" GEq "d" GoTo DIR
Else If "%%~aZ" GEq "-" GoTo FILE
Else GoTo NOTFOUND

:DIR
Echo "Dir Found!"
Pause

:FILE
Echo "File Found!"
Pause

:NOTFOUND
Echo "NOTHING FOUND!"
Pause
```

Comment: An else can't reside on it's own line, it has to directly follow the closing parentheses of the `if condition (code block)  else` See[if /?](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: The help can be read for any command by opening a command prompt and typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question. `IF /?`.  The syntax for `IF ELSE` is clearly defined in the help file.  Since you are not using parentheses, I will assume you made no effort to read the help file.

Comment: @Squashman Here is a link to help you save time w/ your comments --> https://lmgtfy.app/

Comment: You can really see the friendliness of SO w/ questions like this... Is it a duplicate? If so, mark it as one, if not, then it's helping build SO's content base.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking the initial code in the link, and adding parentheses helps to break down the `If` and `Else` structure:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%Z In ("%ATTR%") Do (
    If "%%~aZ" GEq "d" (
        Echo Directory
    ) Else (
        If "%%~aZ" GEq "-" (
            Echo File
        ) Else (
            Echo Inaccessible
        )
    )
)
Pause
```

So to modify it with `GoTo`'s, perhaps something like this is more suitable for your purposes:

```bat
@Echo Off
PushD "%~dp0"
ClS
Set "ATTR=%AppData%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART"
For %%Z In ("%ATTR%") Do (
    If "%%~aZ" GEq "d" (
        GoTo DIR
    ) Else (
        If "%%~aZ" GEq "-" (
            GoTo FILE
        ) Else (
            GoTo NOACCESS
        )
    )
)
GoTo NOTFOUND

:DIR
Echo "Directory Found!"
GoTo ENDFOR

:FILE
Echo "File Found!"
GoTo ENDFOR

:NOTFOUND
Echo "Not Found!"
GoTo ENDFOR

:NOACCESS
Echo "Inaccessible!"

:ENDFOR
Pause
Exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by putting the `GoTo Foo` inside the brackets and making one line which I found easier to read since "ELSE" can't go on it's own line.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
cls
::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954081/check-if-the-path-is-file-or-folder-using-batch 

set "ATTR=%AppData%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART"

::For %%Z In ("%ATTR%") Do If "%%~aZ" GEq "d" (Echo Directory
::) Else If "%%~aZ" GEq "-" (Echo File) Else Echo Inaccessible
::Pause

For %%Z In ("%ATTR%") Do If "%%~aZ" GEq "d" (GoTo DIR) Else If "%%~aZ" GEq "-" (GoTo FILE) Else (GoTo NOTFOUND)

:DIR
Echo "Dir Found!"
Pause
GoTo ENDFOR

:FILE
Echo "File Found!"
Pause
GoTo ENDFOR

:NOTFOUND
Echo "NOTHING FOUND!"
Pause
GoTo ENDFOR

:ENDFOR
```